# JQuery event (with selector) called by my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem, I try to call my jquery event.

I have 2 jquery event:

```
$element.on('click', function (e) { ... });


$element.on('click', '.toggle', function (e) { ... });
```

I would like to call the event with toggle selector. How can I do this?

```
$element.trigger('click', '.toggle') call always the first event.
```

Thank you

Comment: what is `element` in your examples?

Comment: You might have used the same Selector Element in both function

Comment: element is an anchor on my html element

Comment: Elements selected by `$element` and `.toggle` have both two handlers attached, and `$element.trigger('click', '.toggle')` *cannot* distinguish between the two. It's not like that `$element.on('click',...)` and `$element.on('click', '.toggle',...)` creates 2 groups and a `$element.trigger('click', '.toggle')` would matches the latter, it does not work in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks,

now i do:

```
$element.find('toggle').trigger('click')
```

And it runs fine